# DISQUS Ajax reset without #! symbols

Tags: jquery, ajax, disqus

There is a profile page for each user in the website. Say

> `http://www.website.com/profile/profile-id/`

In this page at the left column all the Posts by the user with a small excerpt will be shown. On clicking any of the posts, the complete post will be fetched from the database and displayed at the right column using AJAX.

While each post too have separate URL so that any user can read the post directly with it's URL such as,

> `http://www.website.com/post/post-id/`

I have added DISQUS comments under the POST. These comments load without any issue in the posts page. The issue I face is in the profile page using AJAX, I am not using `#!` for AJAX requests and I want the comments of the post page to be loaded here.

The DISQUS `reset` code used,

```
var reset=function (post_id, post_title)
{
    DISQUS.reset(
    {
        config: function ()
        {
            this.page.identifier = post_id;
            this.page.url = "http://www.website.com/post/"+post_id+"/";
            this.page.title = post_title;
            this.language = "en";
            alert(this.page.url); // This alerts correct as http://www.website.com/post/10001/ (Say)
        },
        reload: true
    });
};
```

This reset function is called from the success part of the AJAX response such as,

```
success: function(data)
{
   if(data.exist==1)
   {
     $('section.load-post').html(data.post_code); // Load the post in the right column
     reset(post_id, data.title); // At any instance reset(10001, sample title)
   }
}
```

The problem is even though the DISQUS comments reload, the comments loaded with respect to the profile URL

> `http://www.website.com/profile/profile-id/`

not the corresponding post URL, i.e.

> `http://www.website.com/post/post-id/`

Comment: Not seeing anything obvious, but I might suspect that the identifier is already associated with a different URL. Is this live somewhere we can see what's happening?

Comment: @RyanV: I am currently using this in my `localhost`